# How to refer table column by column heading/name in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

(I might have used wrong terminology to frame question, and it would be great to be pointed at right question/answer.)

As shown in image I have a table.
I want to sum all the values in "col2"

One way to do this is

`=sum(B2:B4)`

But I think a cleaner way to do this would involve somehow referring the column name in the formula, so that formula is more readable.

Is there a way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try this too

```
=sum(filter(A2:C4,A1:C1="col2"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=SUM(offset(A2:A,,MATCH("Col2",1:1,0)-1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("C"&MATCH("col2", 1:1, 0),FALSE))
```

Output:

[image]

### References:

- [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)
- [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)
- [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en)